# Waiting for spawned threads by active loop fails in Emscripten. How can I modify it?

Tags: emscripten

I try converting some open source C++ project to WebAssembly by Emscripten.
About multi-thread, the project uses active loop with a condition_variable to wait spawn of threads.

```
void spawnMethod() {
    numServerThreadsStartingUp = numThreads;
    for(int i = 0; i<numThreads; i++) {
        std::thread* thread = new std::thread(&aFunction,);
        serverThreads.push_back(thread);
    }
    unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(bufferMutex);
    while(numServerThreadsStartingUp > 0)
        mainThreadWaitingForSpawn.wait(lock);
}

void aFunction() {
    {
        lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(bufferMutex);
        numServerThreadsStartingUp--;
        if(numServerThreadsStartingUp <= 0)
            mainThreadWaitingForSpawn.notify_all();
    }

}
```

In C++, it works well, but in Emscripten it does not work. The child thread never be spawned.
I think that you need to exit spawnMethod, which is invoked as Web Worker, to spawn other threads.
Is my understanding right?
And what is workaround to work?

Thank you.